# Kotlin - Create custom ext function for SpannableStringBuilder without duplicate arguments when declaring start, end & flasg for setSpans()

Tags: kotlin, code-duplication, kotlin-extension, spannablestringbuilder

this is MainActivity.kt before

```
var spannable = SpannableStringBuilder("$noColorText$coloredText")
spannable.setSpan(
    ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(textView.context, R.color.mainGreen)),
    noColorText.length, spannable.length,
    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
)
spannable.setSpan(
    StyleSpan(BOLD),
    noColorText.length, spannable.length,
    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
)
textView.text = spannable
```

Here's my approach so far.

Extension.kt

```
// TODO: e.g: "string".putSpans(start, end, flags) { ForgroundColorSpan(color), StyleSpan(BOLD) }
fun String.putSpans(vararg flags: Int.() -> Unit, spanBuilder: SpannableStringBuilder.() -> Unit):
    SpannableStringBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder(this).apply(spanBuilder)
```

MainActivity.kt

```
// TODO: Change SpannableBuilder to be modular (without, reinput duplicate args)
val resultSpan = "$noColorText$coloredText ".putSpans {
    setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(textView.context, R.color.mainGreen)),
        noColorText.length, this.length, // this is duplicate
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE) // this is duplicate
    setSpan(StyleSpan(BOLD),
        noColorText.length, this.length, // this is duplicate
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE) // this is duplicate
    }

textView.text = resultSpan
```

Is this possible to create extension like this

```
"string".putSpans(start, end, flags) { ForgroundColorSpan(color), StyleSpan(BOLD) }
```

so we don't have to use duplicate start, end, also flags argument, but open for modification, e.g:

```
"string".putSpans(start, end, flags) { // for default value
 span(ForgroundColorSpan(color), diffStart, diffEnd), 
 span(StyleSpan(BOLD), diffFlags) 
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use extensions included in `core-ktx` which simplify using, more specifically, building `SpannedString` in kotlin as so:

```
buildSpannedString {
    bold {
        append("hitherejoe")
    }
}
```

I guess you would use it like this:

```
buildSpannedString {
    bold {
        inSpans(ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(textView.context, R.color.mainGreen))) {
            append("string")
        }
    }
}
```

See [androidx.text](https://android.github.io/android-ktx/core-ktx/androidx.text/index.html) package for reference.

I took the example from [this](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-ktx-for-android-13a369795b51) Medium post by Joe Birch.

Comment: thanks for the answer @maroš-Šeleng, I really appreciate it!

I'm gonna try it tonight.